# Will I pay tax to transfer money from one of my bank account to my other bank account?

Tags: income-tax

I have 3 bank accounts in 3 different banks. One I opened during college days.  The other 2 were provided by companies when joined. All my 3 accounts are added with my pan number. If I transfer money from one of my account to the my other account, will I have to pay tax for the same?

Comment: You pay tax on money you earn, this includes any interest earned in your accounts.

Comment: In what country?  In the US, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no taxes for transferring money from one bank account to other bank account. There could be a NEFT/RTGS transfer fee charged by the bank but nothing else.